# Linking multiple DIVs to multiple categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problems with some Wordpress/ PHP code. I already linked DIVS with categories by using:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if(in_category( 'In prijs verlaagd') ) { ?>
  <div class="object col-md-4 verlaagd">
          <?php wpfp_link() ?>

  <?php }elseif(in_category( 'Tijdelijk niet beschikbaar')){ ?>
  <div class="object col-md-4 onhold">
      <?php wpfp_link() ?         
  <?php }else{ ?>
  <div class="object col-md-4">
      <?php wpfp_link() ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

But I can't seem to add multiple divs with multiple categories. I already tried:

```
<?php elseif(in_category( 'PerceelsID aangevraagd')&& in_category ( 'In prijs verlaagd') ) { ?>
     <div class="object col-md-4 verlaagd">
     <div class="object col-md-4 aangevraagd">
 <div id="aangevraagd"></div>
  <?php wpfp_link() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're second code-block isn't complete since you're starting with `elseif`. If the `elseif` statement is preceded by an `if` statement that is true, the `elseif` statement will not be tested. You could do something like this:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 
$extraclass = '';
if(in_category( 'In prijs verlaagd') ) { 
    $extraclass .= 'verlaagd';
}

if(in_category( 'Tijdelijk niet beschikbaar')){ 
    $extraclass .= 'onhold';
}
?>
<div class="object col-md-4 <?php echo $extraclass ?>">
<?php wpfp_link() ?>
```